# How to rebind the removed event of an anchor tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am unbinding the event based on the condition, once if the condition is true I am using jQuery off method when condition is false I need to bind the click event for anchor. 
 I tried the below code but I am unable to achieve it.

**Code : **

```
$('select').change(function(){
    if($(this).val()=='mas'){
        alert("inside");
     $("#lnk").off('click');   
    }else
    {
        alert('else');
        $("#lnk").on('click','.add');
    }
});

$("a").on('click',function(){
    alert('Iam clciked');
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<select>
    <option val=''>Seect</option>
    <option val='ind'>Ind</option>
    <option val='mas'>mas</option>
</select>
<a href='#' class='add' id='lnk'>Go</a>
```

**Fiddler Link : **

//

[http://jsfiddle.net/md5psv28/](http://jsfiddle.net/md5psv28/2/)

Answer (score 1):

You have this:

```
$("#lnk").on('click','.add');
```

Here, in the second argument of your `on` method, the ''.add'' is not a valid `function/handler`. You need to pass the `function/handler` here that you want to `bind` with it, instead you've passed a `class`.

You may try it like this:

```
$("a").on('click', addHandler);

function addHandler(){
    alert('Iam clciked');
}
```

[Updated Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/md5psv28/4/)

Comment: That's what he's asking how to do.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just place the click handler within a function, and call it initially.

```
function bindClick() {
    $("a").off('click').on('click', function () {
        alert('Clicked.');
    });
}
bindClick();
```

Then when the condition isn't satisfied, just call the function again to rebind it.

```
$('select').change(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == 'mas') {
        $("#lnk").off('click');
    } else {
        bindClick();
    }
});
```

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/p3Ln3co2/)